# How to decrease the size of horizontal bar at report?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I'm creating a Jasper report with horizontal bar, and I have a problem with one of my bars from the chart; the last one is very much bigger than the others, and it is cutting in half of the value of the label.

How can I adjust to not surpass a specific value of the chart?

Comment: Try `setUpperMargin()` on your range axis.

Comment: Hey @trashgod, I'm going to try and update here, thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @trashgod for your help, with the **setUpperMargin()** method it worked to decrease the size of the horizontal bar.

To anyone with the same problem as I was having, my code to fix it is below:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
  NumberAxis numAxis =  (NumberAxis) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRangeAxis();
  numAxis.setUpperMargin(0.25);
}
```

Documentation:
[ValueAxis - JFreeChart](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setUpperMargin-double-)